# Connecting and fetching data from mysql using angularjs

Tags: java, mysql, angularjs

I am new to angularjs , can anybody guide me in performing CRUD operations in MYSQL and display in html form using angularjs... to be more precise... I want to store information to customer details such has name,consumer number,contact,address and update the same whenever necessary using java..

Answer (score 1):

Hello and welcome to SO,

I created this diagram in order to make you feel more comfortable with the subject.

[image: CRUD]

As you may see I didn't mention any language: Client, Server nor Database, because the language itself has nothing to do with REST APIs.

Instructions - begginer:

(If you are using PHP, I'd recommend SlimFramework, which is the light, scale, easy to start with, PHP Framework).

> 1) Pick a server-side language.
>
> 2) Create a Database Resource.
>
> 3) Pick a Server Side Language.
>
> 4) Create 4 Scripts that each does one of each:
>   Create,Read,Update,Delete.
>
> 5) Connect endpoints with each of the scripts, URL -
>   GET,POST,DELETE,UPDATE.
>
> 6) Verify that you can access each of them from the web (authenticated
>   or not).
>
> 7) After you verified that endpoints are working, time to connect
>   Angular:
>
> 7a) First try to create buttons for each action, and link it with
>   $http.get, $http.post, $http.delete, $http.put actions.
>
> 7b) Once it's working you might wanna step up and use ng-resource or
>   restangular.

P.S: I didn't supply much code information since once you understand what I stated on top, you'd realize that writing code for that isn't really hard.

After you complete these ,
**You might wanna start with: Server side and Client side authentication, Performance, Multiple resources and collections, CORS and preflighted requests, and so on.**

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for your xplanatory diagram and steps... :)

Comment: You are welcome, after you finish those steps you will be much more comfortable doing much more.